# what is the linux command to filter out files with read access?

Tags: linux, hadoop

There are hundreds of files in a directory in linux system. Could anyone help me how to list out only those files I have read access for?

Answer (score -1):

try this.

```
find . -type f \! -perm /u=r
```

this should find all files that you have only read access to.